# Automatically pausing a Virtualbox VM if it receives no KB/mouse input

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, virtual-desktop

I am running a `Windows 10` guest on my `Macbook Pro MacOS 10.12`.

In order to conserve the resources and battery of the host, I'd like to be able to pause the guest if the guest receives no keyboard or mouse input for a specified amount of time.

Is this possible on `Virtualbox`?

If not, I am open to the prospect of using a scripting language such as `bash`, `powershell` or `python` to achieve my goal. Any pointers in this area greatly appreciated (I don't expect anyone to write code for me).

Comment: Almost any guest will idle down and not use resources if not being used. All my virtual machines are like that.  Memory will be used by having the guest loaded and that is normal.

Comment: @John correct me if I'm wrong but a paused guest will use zero resources except allocated RAM, whereas what you are talking about would still be using resources, albeit minimally?

Comment: I assume by "Resources" you mean CPU resources. Right now I have one Host and 3 virtual machines running.  CPU is < 5%.   Memory is fixed by what is allotted to the machine and cannot be released without shutting the machine down.

Comment: Why not set the guest to sleep after idle?

Comment: @harrymc, how do I set the guest to sleep after idle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMware Workstation (Virtual Box is similar) cannot pause a guest with no input, but the process (you want) to reduce resource consumption is already there and automatic like any real system.

If the guest is not being actively used, then CPU resource will sink to a logical minimum. I have 3 guests running on a Windows 10 host and CPU resource has been showing <5% for several hours now (other that tiny short spurts overall).

Of course memory is used by running guests and can only be released by shutting down guests.

So within logical reason, what you want is already there.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox cannot do that, it's much simpler to set the Windows VM to sleep
after a certain idle time.

To get to this setting, click the Start button and run `Power Options`.
Next to your selected power plan, click "Change plan settings",
set the idle time and click "Save chances".

---

[image]